# Encryption difference between java and android

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm using RSA encryption with public key in my java app to send my data to server. Everything is ok when i use java to do that but when i trying to do same thing with android i'm getting following error in server:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
```

This is my code on android and java to encrypt data:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Encryption {
    private static String base64Encode(byte[] bytes) {
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
    }

    private static void crypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out, Cipher cipher) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
        int outputSize = cipher.getOutputSize(blockSize);
        byte[] inBytes = new byte[blockSize];
        byte[] outBytes = new byte[outputSize];

        int inLength = 0;
        boolean more = true;
        while (more) {
            inLength = in.read(inBytes);
            if (inLength == blockSize) {
                int outLength = cipher.update(inBytes, 0, blockSize, outBytes);
                out.write(outBytes, 0, outLength);
            } else more = false;
        }
        if (inLength > 0) outBytes = cipher.doFinal(inBytes, 0, inLength);
        else outBytes = cipher.doFinal();

        out.write(outBytes);
    }

    public static String encryptWithPublicKey(String property) {
        String result = null;

        KeyGenerator keygen;
        SecureRandom random;
        Key publicKey;
        SecretKey key;
        Cipher cipher;

        ObjectInputStream keyIn = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        DataOutputStream out = null;
        InputStream in = null;

        try {
            keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            random = new SecureRandom();
            keygen.init(random);
            key = keygen.generateKey();

            keyIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("public.key"));
            publicKey = (Key) keyIn.readObject();

            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, publicKey);
            byte[] wrappedKey = cipher.wrap(key);

            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            out = new DataOutputStream(baos);
            out.writeInt(wrappedKey.length);
            out.write(wrappedKey);

            in = new ByteArrayInputStream(property.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            crypt(in, out, cipher);

            result = base64Encode(baos.toByteArray());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Util.close(baos);
            Util.close(out);
            Util.close(in);
            Util.close(keyIn);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Result is fine when i use the `encryptWithPublicKey` from java code but i have error when i use it from android! what is the deffernece between these two systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably happening because you've not specified the full `algorithm/mode/padding` options for your `Cipher` objects.

So change `"RSA"` to `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"`, for example. And `"AES"` to `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`. Or whatever values are appropriate.

Reason: different crypto providers have different default values for padding and mode. If you just specify the algorithm, you are relying on the defaults which may not be compatible between different systems.

Comment: I changed my code to what you said and the error changed to this: 'java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters'

Comment: The problem was inside this line: keygen.init(random); and i changed it to keygen.init(128);

Comment: @S.Yavari Your second error was caused by not having the unlimited strength jurisdiction files installed on your machine. Google for that and you'll see what fix to apply (if legal to do so for you).